# not all log messages are getting written in file in multithreaded env using log4j

Tags: java, multithreading, log4j

i am using log4j to write logs to a file. 
My application is multithreaded.
While the program executes i can see the logs on console but when i open the configured log file where the log was supposed to be written, it contains only a few logs and rest of the logs are missing.
Can anyone please suggest anything i need to check as what might be causing the issue.

Also, the same log4j.xml config file when used in simple (not threaded) application works fine and prints out all logs to the desired file.

Comment: check your configuration what you are logging. it is possible you've configured it to only log 'Error' messages, or only 'Debug' messages to your log file, while you are expecting to see the 'Information' logs there as well.

Comment: i have checked that possibility and that configuration is fine.. The same log4j.xml when used in simple application writes out logs perfectly fine in the corresponding log file.